# Why my JSON format change after set it to the entities redux toolkit

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have current problem in my entity adapter after I receive the response from the api and set the payload to the state it happen is the json format change. I don't know if the **setOne** method of redux toolkit change it by self.

**Original Format :**

```
{
    "id": "af3fbedf-4751-413b-abd5-074737b6edd2",
    "role_id": null,
    "first_name": "Geirge",
    "last_name": "Shaw",
    "email": "sdf@sdf.com",
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "username": "coder",
    "status": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-11-18T06:50:46.000000Z",
    "created_by": null,
    "updated_at": "2021-11-18T06:50:46.000000Z",
    "updated_by": null,
    "fullname": "Geirge Shaw",
    "token": "94|4O0z51gddqHxeCs5UhLysE9QoSsIOSlP2EYb9iFQ"
}
```

**New Format after I set the response to the state:**

```
af3fbedf-4751-413b-abd5-074737b6edd2: {id: 'af3fbedf-4751-413b-abd5-074737b6edd2', role_id: null, first_name: .....}
```

**ExtraReducers Looks Like:**

```
extraReducers: {
  [LoginAuthentication.pending](state, action){
    state.isLoading = true
    state.isLoggedIn = false
  },
  [LoginAuthentication.fulfilled](state, {payload}){
    console.log(payload);
    state.isLoading = false
    LoginAdapter.setOne(state, payload)
    state.isLoggedIn = true
  },
  [LoginAuthentication.rejected](state, action) {
    state.isLoading = false
    state.isLoggedIn = false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that is exactly what `createEntityAdapter` does. It takes the original item objects, and stores them in a lookup table where the keys are the IDs and the values are the original items.

See these resources for more explanations:

- https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#normalized-state
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#using-createentityadapter
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#managing-normalized-data
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter